# How to filter for multiple tests in PHPUnit?

Tags: php, phpunit

I am able to run a single test from a suite using `--filter` option.

I am wondering if there is a way to dynamically run multiple tests under the suite?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by *dynamically* ?

Answer (score 15):

A simple regex to filter for multiple tests could look like `--filter '/test1|test2|test4/'`. This will match any tests which contain 'test1' 'test2' or 'test4' so for example test43 would be included, but test3 would not get run. The check is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 4):

Work for me :

```
phpunit -c phpunit.dist.xml src --filter '/NameSpace\\UserBundle/|Namespace\\OtherBundle'
```

Do not work for me :

```
phpunit -c phpunit.dist.xml src --filter "/NameSpace\\UserBundle/|Namespace\\OtherBundle"
```

Whit double quote the result for me is "No tests executed!"

If you don't use \ in filter (for namespace) then double quote work perfectly but with namespace\bundle on my setup I need to use single quote.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the **--group** option.

You just need to add **@group** annotation to your methods like this:

```
/**
 * @group test1
 */
 public function test_example(){
 ...
```

Add **@group** to tests you want to run or group similar test into groups with the same **@group** name.

Run all tests that has a group with:

```
phpunit --group test1
```

Answer (score 0):

The --filter option runs tests whose name matches the given regular expression pattern, so you should be able to select multiple tests by providing a suitable regular expression as argument.

See the documentation for the [PHPUnit command line test runner](http://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.1/textui.html)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend usage of "spatie/phpunit-watcher" (https://github.com/spatie/phpunit-watcher) that will allow you to perform this type of filtering

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up creating my own configuration file with all the tests that I need and then pass it via `--configuration` to PHPUnit.

Answer (score 0):

On your code, you can have the same pattern for the methods on the test class like this:

```
testUserShow()
testUserStore()
testUserUpdate()
testUserDestroy()
```

When using `--filter <pattern>`, if you do `--filter=testUser` it will do all these methods with that pattern.

You can chose other [selections](https://docs.phpunit.de/en/10.0/textui.html?highlight=--filter#selection) for testing.