# PhpUnit how to run --filter with multiple conditions

Tags: php, filter, phpunit

I have seen [How to run single test method with phpunit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26095051/how-to-run-single-test-method-with-phpunit)

And I have no trouble applying a filter eg `--filter=SomeTest` but I want to be able to check a number of test files in one command line eg, `--filter=SomeTest, SomeOtherTest` but this does not work.

Is there a way I can do this from the command line?

Comment: There are answers to this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50800071/using-phpunits-filter-option-for-multiple-tests

Comment: was this pipe syntax documented anywhere on phpunit's site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works `--filter="SomeTest|SomeOtherTest"`

According to documentation found here:
https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/8.5/textui.html#command-line-options

Any regex pattern will also work.
"If the pattern is not enclosed in delimiters, PHPUnit will enclose the pattern in / delimiters."

Also helped me to read about regular expressions:
https://sitespect.force.com/onlinehelp/s/article/About-Regular-Expressions-1459718276